# jQuery plugin in an Underscore.js template

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm using Backbone.js and I got a Underscore.js template which contain a Reveal modal (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html). The fact is when I render my template and I press a button that is supposed to open my Reveal , it doesn't do anything. When I watch the source code I can find my element reveal modal , so I think the problem comes from jQuery...

Here is a simplified version of my template (just as an example) :

```
<script type="text/template" id="myTemplate">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
            <label>I'm the modal</label>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
        </div>
        <button data-reveal-id="myModal" id="btnModal"></button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you checked that fondation.js and foundation.js and foundation.reveal.js are included in your web page ?

Comment: What's the code to open the Reveal modal, do yuo see any javascript errors in console ?

Comment: Nop , there is nothing in the console. Yes Feugy , I've check. When I use reveal out of the template it work, it's only in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed tho initialize Foundation at the end of the template (to put some javaScript in a underscore.js template you use <% .... %> )
So my template is now :

```
<script type="text/template" id="myTemplate">
<div class="row">
    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
        <label>I'm the modal</label>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
    <button data-reveal-id="myModal" id="btnModal"></button>
</div>
<% $(document).foundation(); %>
</script>
```

Thanks to the man who answer this morning , I can't remember his name because he delete his answer , but he definitively help me find the solution.